# Efficiency of sequential algorithm executed on machine with 60Gb RAM

Tags: java, algorithm, cloud, virtual-machine

Will sequential algorithm written in Java execute faster (in Eclipse) on a machine with 60Gb RAM and 16 cores, if compared to a dual-core machine with 16Gb RAM? I expected that the algorithm would really run faster, but experiments on a Google Compute Engine and my laptop showed that it's not a truth. I appreciate if someone could explain why this happens.

Comment: Why did you expect that the former would be faster than the latter?. Also, the time complexity of an algorithm will not be dependent on the machine. Next, are you using multiple threads?. How did you benchmark this?

Comment: @Vinod Madyalkar: I'm a novice in the algorithm's enhancement. Sorry if my question sounds simply. No, I don't use threads, because it's impossible to parallelize my algorithm. It's a Simulated Annealing. I guess it's sequential. If I used Genetic Algorithms, I would able to create multiple threads, but I prefer SA for its efficiency.

Comment: There are multiple factors that determine how a program performs.  You might see different results for multiple runs of the program on the same machine. That's why you should always think in terms of *time complexity* :)

Comment: More RAM does not means that you can run everything faster. You will get more speed if you can cache all data in one machine while the other machine needs to swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't parallize the code automatically for you, you need to do it yourself.

There are some abstractions that like `parallel streams` that give you concise parallelism, but still, the performance of your program is governed by [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) . Having more memory will help in launching more threads and applying parallel algorithms for leveraging more cores.

Example:

- **Arrays.sort** is a sequential **Dual-Pivot Quicksort** that runs in O(nlgn) time, its overall performance governed by the clock rate.
- **Arrays.parallelSort** is parallel merge-sort, it uses more space ( so here memory is important ), it divided the array into pieces and sort each piece and merge them.

But, someone had to write this parallel sort in order to benefit from multicores machines.

What could be done automatically for you, is a highly concurrent and parallel GC that effects the overall performance of your program.

Comment: You will also have to consider the overhead of context switching between threads. A CPU intensive operation could perform better on a PC with several cores assuming you are actually making proper use of the underlying CPU cores.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar is true, I added a link to Amdahl's law so the OP can start from there before they get desperate :)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for `sequential algorithm`, which clearly means there are no multiple threads, no parallelism or multi-processing involved in the execution of the code. Lets say, the code is:

```
a = 5;
b = a + 5;
c = b + 5;
...
and so on...
```

We cannot execute any of the latter lines because of their dependency on the former values.

A simple loop,

```
for i from 1 to 100 increment 1
    a = a + i
```

will have to be executed 100 times, in order, as that would create a difference in result, and hence cannot be parallelized.

Also, since you are not using threads in your code, `java` has no support for parallelism inbuilt, so there go your chances even if the code was a bit parallelizable.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single threaded piece of code, the system it will run on has some influence on the execution time. This is measured by the IPC

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle

You code will definitely run faster on a newer system than a 10 year old, but maybe the difference between the two machines you mentioned for 1 thread are not significant enough.